# spring boot TaskExecutor thread pool size

Tags: spring-boot

I am use spring boot 2.0.2, and use Async to execute tasks.

I register a TaskExecutor to control thread pool size, like below:

```
public class ThreadConfig {
@Bean
public TaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {

    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();

    executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(3);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(3);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("anniversary");

    executor.initialize();
    System.out.println("******* name "  + executor.getThreadNamePrefix());
    System.out.println("********** core pool size " + executor.getCorePoolSize());

    return executor;
}

}
```

But during running, there are more than 20 threads are created,

```
*********Thread[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1,5,com.abc.team1.project1.anniversary.AnniversaryApplication]*********
**********Thread[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-2,5,com.abc.team1.project1.anniversary.AnniversaryApplication]*********
**********Thread[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-3,5,com.abc.team1.project1.anniversary.AnniversaryApplication]*********
**********Thread[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-4,5,com.abc.team1.project1.anniversary.AnniversaryApplication]*********
**********Thread[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-5,5,com.abc.team1.project1.anniversary.AnniversaryApplication]*********
**********Thread[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-6,5,com.abc.team1.project1.anniversary.AnniversaryApplication]*********
**********Thread[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-7,5,com.abc.team1.project1.anniversary.AnniversaryApplication]*********
**********Thread[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-8,5,com.abc.team1.project1.anniversary.AnniversaryApplication]*********
**********Thread[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-9,5,com.abc.team1.project1.anniversary.AnniversaryApplication]*********
**********Thread[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-10,5,com.abc.team1.project1.anniversary.AnniversaryApplication]*********
**********Thread[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-11,5,com.abc.team1.project1.anniversary.AnniversaryApplication]*********
**********Thread[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-12,5,com.abc.team1.project1.anniversary.AnniversaryApplication]*********
**********Thread[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-13,5,com.abc.team1.project1.anniversary.AnniversaryApplication]*********
**********Thread[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-14,5,com.abc.team1.project1.anniversary.AnniversaryApplication]*********
```

Comment: I found the solution, I need to add a name attribute, like :          @Bean(name = "taskExecutor")
    public TaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {

Comment: what's the meaning of "SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1,5", the second "5"?